# Multiple insert in MySql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

[Graphical representation of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDdpA.png)

What I am trying to achieve is when the user clicks on [submit], all the drop downs and form selections must be inserted into the database.

This is the query I am using:

```
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO UserRequests(
    `UserId`,
    `ConstituencyId`,
    `RequestCategoryId`,
    `Request`,
    `CreatedOn`
  ) VALUES (
    '" . $_SESSION["userId"] . "',
    '" . $_SESSION["ConstituencyId"] . "',
    '" . $_POST['selection'] . "',
    '" . $_POST['txtTitle'] . "',
    '" . $date . "'
  )";
```

On the form, there is a button for the user to add and delete rows from the form, so when it is submitted, there is no fixed length for `$_POST`. If user clicks the button then a new row is added to the form. In that row Dropdown menu is there, text box is there. If user clicks the submit button all rows data (including the newly added form rows) must be inserted into table called UserRequests.

I Am learning PHP, I am a beginner.

If 5 rows of data is there those 5 rows of Dropdown menu data and 5 Rows of Text field data be inserted into database.
Please Help on this.
Thanks.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO UserRequests(
      `UserId`,
      `ConstituencyId`,
      `RequestCategoryId`,
      `Request`,
      `CreatedOn`
    ) VALUES (
      '" . $_SESSION["userId"] . "',
      '" . $_SESSION["ConstituencyId"] . "',
      '" . $_POST['selection'] . "',
      '" . $_POST['txtTitle'] . "',
      '" . $date . "'
    )";

    $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);
?>

<div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center">User Requests Section</h3>
        <hr class="horizontal-line">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table" id="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <select name="selection">
                                <?php
                                    foreach ($result3 as $RequestCategories) 
                                    {
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $RequestCategories["Id"]; ?>">
                                    <?php echo $RequestCategories["RequestCategory"]; ?></option>
                                <?php }?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle" placeholder="Enter Your Description" required="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="removebutton" title="Remove this row">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><!-- End of Row -->
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <button id="addbutton">Add Row</button>
    </div> <!-- End of Container -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
$("#addbutton").click(function () {
 $("#table tr:first").clone().find("input").each(function () {
     $(this).val('').attr({
         'id': function (_, id) {
             return id + i
         },
             'name': function (_, name) {
             return name + i
         },
             'value': ''
     });
 }).end().appendTo("#table");
 i++;
 });

 $(document).on('click', 'button.removebutton', function () {
 alert("Delete row");
 $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 return false;
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Help with what?

Comment: this is a single form and when user click's on submit button then only single record add into the database. there is no multiple query concepts..

Comment: How to insert Multiple Rows ?

Comment: _“I Dont know how to use arrays”_ - then you should really start by fixing that first of all - go read some books or beginner’s tutorials on the matter, please. SO is not a place to give private tutoring on the very basics over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you will need a `foreach` loop to repeatedly run the query, as it can be an unspecified length. And also, since you are making use of `$_SESSION`, you will need to initialise the session.

Assuming that `selection` and `txtTitle` are the only fields you are posting, you can array_chunk() to split the array into two parts (after unsetting unwanted vars, of course)

```
<?php

    //Initialise the session
    session_start();

    //You have a button "submit" in your post that will mess up this loop.
    //Remove it so it won't be an issue
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )unset( $_POST['submit'] );

    /**
    * Each row consists of 2 inputs, and so we want to array_chunk($_POST, 2),
    * so that the structure will be as follows:
    *
    *  $_POST = array(
    *      [0] => array(
    *          ["selection"] => "select_value",
    *          ["txtTitle"] => "text_value",
    *        ),
    *      [1] => array(
    *          ["selection"] => "select_value",
    *          ["txtTitle"] => "text_value",
    *        ),
    *    );
    * 
    * But you don't need to know much more than that for now, but arrays _always_ start at 0
    *
    **/
   $values = array_chunk( $_POST, 2 );

   //This is the output
   $output = array();

   //Now that we split up the input, we are left with the rows
   foreach($values as $key=>$row){
       /**
       * Rows will be structured as this
       *
       * $row = array(
       *    ["selection"] => "select_value",
       *    ["txtTitle"] => "text_value",
       *   );
       **/

       $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO UserRequests(
            `UserId`,
            `ConstituencyId`,
            `RequestCategoryId`,
            `Request`,
            `CreatedOn`
          ) VALUES (
            '" . $_SESSION["userId"] . "',
            '" . $_SESSION["ConstituencyId"] . "',
            '" . $_POST['selection'] . "',
            '" . $_POST['txtTitle'] . "',
            '" . $date . "'
          )";

       //Insert this row to the database
       $conn->query($insertQuery);

       //Add the insertion count to an array
       $output[] = $conn->num_rows . " row has been inserted.";
   }

   print_r( $output, 1 );
?>
```